# Python - Sampling imbalanced dataset

Tags: python, pandas, machine-learning, random, sample

I have a dataset with 3 classes and below are the value_counts().

```
Class 0 - 2000
Class 1 - 10000
Class 2 - 10000
```

I want to sample this dataset with the distribution as below.

```
Class 0 - 2000 (i.e., all rows from Class 0)
Class 1 - 4000 (i.e., twice as many rows as Class 0)
Class 2 - 4000 (i.e., twice as many rows as Class 0)
```

Random sampling using weights retrieves only a fraction of Class 0. Please advice.

Comment: "Please advice": sounds like it's doing what it should be doing!  https://stats.stackexchange.com/ is more for stats questions.  if you really want that distribution, then why not make it? i.e. create a dataframe filtered for just rows of "Class 0", then append 4000 random rows of "Class 1", and again for "Class 2"...

Comment: Thank you Sam. In fact, that's exactly how I'm doing it right now (creating separate DFs for each class and concatenating them), but felt it to be a naive approach. So wanted to know if there is any other way to do it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand you correctly:

```py
# Create sample data
df = pd.DataFrame({"class": np.repeat([0, 1, 2], [2_000, 10_000, 10_000])})

# The distribution matrix
distribution = {0: 2000, 1: 4000, 2: 4000}

# Take samples based on the distribution matrix
sample = pd.concat(
    [group.sample(distribution[class_]) for class_, group in df.groupby("class")]
)
```